# Access root BASE API URL from a child (or deep sub-child) elements in Polymer 1.0

Tags: ajax, polymer-1.0

I have created many elements in my Polymer 1.0 environment. Some elements are lists based on data I get from my DB server using iron-ajax. Currently I am using my root application to pass in the API URL as an element property to each element (or sub-element) that requires it so it may make the call and display the results.

Something feels off about the approach though. Should I be passing in AJAX URLs from the root element to the child elements that require it or is there a way for child elements to know what the globally set app API URL is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue, fortunately

> There is an element for that :)

So I've created a custom element to wrap all of my `iron-ajax` elements in my application, called it `my-app-api`.

This `my-app-api` element is responsible to update nested `iron-ajax` url attribute.

```
<dom-module id="my-app-api">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <content select="iron-ajax"></content>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
(function() {
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-app-api',

    properties: {
      baseUrl: {
        type: String,
        value: 'http://localhost:9000'
      }
    },
    attached: function() {
      this.updateUrlsAndSign();
    },
    updateUrlsAndSign: function() {

      var ajaxElements = Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('iron-ajax');

      var ajaxElementsArray = [].slice.call(ajaxElements);

      ajaxElementsArray.forEach(function(ajax) {

        var urlAttr = ajax.getAttribute('url');

        if ( !urlAttr ) { return; }

        ajax.url = this.baseUrl + urlAttr.replace(window.location.origin, '');

        ajax.headers = ajax.headers || {};

        ajax.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

        ...

      }.bind(this));
    }
  });
})();
</script>
```

Example usage,

```
<my-app-api>
<iron-ajax
    url="/api/videos/"
    params="{{requestParams}}"
    handle-as="json"
    on-response="handleResponse"></iron-ajax>
</my-app-api>
```

I haven't tested it with `auto` attribute set on `iron-ajax` elements.

In my case that wasn't an issue so the above code worked fine with me.

Hope this will help you implement a better solution.

Comment: I did a similar thing (wrapping iron in my API element) but I don't like the idea of hard coding my base API URL in the element. What if the element is shared with someone using a different port? If I make the port a parameter that is passed in to my wrapper then I am passing in a port Parma to every single element and sub wrapper  - which doesn't seem right either...

Comment: one other more question, @Mohammad:

How do you handle session tokens and user ID updates for request headers? Do you pass them into iron-ajax element every time?

Comment: @Sean sure, that's the rest of `updateUrlsAndSign()` function